# Comparing a value from a variable to values from the given column to check if value exists or not in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, comparison

Suppose I have vehicle plate numbers in a given table "plates" with name of the column as "plate".

I'm taking a plate number as input and keeping it in a variable `num1` and then check whether the plate number is present in the column or not. I tried using

```
db.plates.find( { plate: { $eq: num1 }
```

but it is not returning any output.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I suggest [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50639436/edit) and simply showing a document you expect to match and the actual value of the variable you are trying to match against. Then we don't need to "suppose" anything because we can simply see it. Please take the tour and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) while your at it, but preferably just post the information first and read it later

Comment: have you tried db.plates.find( { plate:  num1 }); u can get